# In scikit-learn, the load_files function is reading in unwanted text files

Tags: python, file-io, scikit-learn

I am using the `load_files` function in sci-kit learn to load 2 simple text documents.

The set up is painfully simple. My files are named `file1` and `file2`.
The first file consists of the text `pig cow chicken`, whereas the second file consists of the the text `pig car truck`.

They both reside here:

```
/home/me/Dropbox/test
```

So far so good.

Now, I use the `load_files` function, as such,

```
text_data = load_files('/home/me/Dropbox/test', encoding='latin-1')
```

Next, I examine
`text_data.filenames`
...and it turns out I'm getting some weird extra files!

```
[ '/home/me/Dropbox/test/folder1/document2.txt'
  '/home/me/Dropbox/test/folder1/document2.txt~'
  '/home/me/Dropbox/test/folder1/document1.txt~'
  '/home/me/Dropbox/test/folder1/document1.txt']
```

I check out the
`text_data.data`
and get:

```
[u'pig\ncar\ntruck\n', u'', u'', u'pig\ncow\nchicken\n']
```

I assume there is something going on here with hidden files, or temp files, or something of those sorts.  Neither of my files are open.  I've restarted iPython, restarted the laptop, etc.  I use `ls -lart` and I see them in the directory.

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

I would like to know a good way to get rid of them, which will solve the problem in this particular instance, but beyond that, I'm wondering why this happened and how I can make sure it doesn't happen again.  What is the mechanism behind these hidden files coming into existence, and why does the function load them?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks!!

Comment: files ending in `~` are usually backup files made by some text editor. Why don't you just remove them? In dropbox folders on unix, there's also usually a `.dropbox` file created automatically - it doesn't seem to be included in your list however.

Comment: Those files are not hidden. Hidden files have a name starting with a period, and IIRC `load_files` will skip those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are likely the backup files created automatically by text editors, such as vim.

To remove all files ending with `~` under the current directory recursively, you can use this command:

```
find -name "*~" -delete
```

Now the question is whether you really want to use `sklearn.datasets.load_files` to load the files. It's designed to load text files with categories as subfolder names, which doesn't seem to be the case for your directory. If you just want to load two simple text documents, wouldn't the built-in `open` function suffice?

Comment: Ugh.  Why oh why does such a quaint and seemingly harmless editor such as vim take such liberties with a user's files?

I am using a dumbed down example here; I do indeed plan to use categories as subfolder names.